# Unable to Restore aws elastic redis from s3 while migrating from one region to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I am trying to migrate my aws elastic redis from one region to another Region. Followed [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-redis-migrate-best-practices/).

1. took the backup of source region redis
2. Created the s3 bucket at the same source region and provide the necessary ACL permission Like adding canonical details
3. Import the backup to source s3 bucket (2 files as having 2 shards)
4. copied the .rdb file to destination s3 bucket
5. added the permission like canonical details
6. Tried to create the new redis on destination region via exporting from s3 bucket but getting below error

Error:

> Unable to fetch metadata from S3 for bucket: s3: and object: /Bucket/backup.rdb. Please verify the input.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error earlier after some try i was able to fix it.

Object loacation format will be like this "my-test-poc-redis/test-bacup.rdb" no slash no "s3://"